# Integrate TvML into native tvOS app

Tags: swift, tvos, tvml

I'd like to play a video in a native tvOS app with the look and feel of the TVML based menuBarTemplate, but can't find a way to integrate this into a native app. So the question is, if it is somehow possible to integrate the menuBarTemplate into a native tvOS app written in Swift

Comment: Have you looked at this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38609694/tvml-document-in-swift-tvos-project/38616488#38616488 ?

Answer (score 1):

Which part of the menuBarTemplate?

The tabbar is a widget that you can drop into the storyboard.

The text list is likely a stack view or an embedded tableview.

That nice image scrolly thing on the left is would be uiviews or something? It's a shame all the TVML widgets didn't come over to TVos UIKit.