# How to use a TVML document in a Swift tvOS project?

Tags: swift, tvos, tvml

I have a project for tvOS written in Swift. Now I received a TVML document that I need to use in my project. What should I do? Can I initialise a `UIViewController` instance with a TVML document?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[TVMLKitchen](https://github.com/toshi0383/TVMLKitchen) helps to embed TVML documents in tvOS apps written in Swift. It has everything that I need to solve my problem and it is easy to use. I hope that it will be useful for all tvOS developers.